# "hadoop streaming failed with error code 5"

Tags: r, hadoop, rhadoop

I have created a multi-node hadoop cluster using my two laptops and have successfully tested it. 
After that I have installed RHadoop upon the hadoop environment. All the necessary packages are installed and path variables are set.

Then, trying to run a wordcount example as follows:

```
map <- function(k,lines) {

   words.list <- strsplit(lines, "\\s")

   words <- unlist(words.list)

   return(keyval(words, 1))

}

reduce <- function(word, counts) {

 keyval(word, sum(counts))

}

wordcount <- function(input, output = NULL) {

   mapreduce(input = input, output = output, input.format = "text", map = map, reduce = reduce)

}

hdfs.root <- "wordcount"
hdfs.data <- file.path(hdfs.root, "data")
hdfs.out <- file.path(hdfs.root, "out")
out <- wordcount(hdfs.data, hdfs.out)
```

I get the following error:

```
15/05/24 21:09:20 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15/05/24 21:09:20 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15/05/24 21:09:20 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with     processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
15/05/24 21:09:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area     file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/master91618435/.staging/job_local91618435_0001
15/05/24 21:09:21 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Error Launching job : No such file or directory
Streaming Command Failed!
Error in mr(map = map, reduce = reduce, combine = combine, vectorized.reduce,  : 
  hadoop streaming failed with error code 5
Called from: mapreduce(input = input, output = output, input.format = "text", 
    map = map, reduce = reduce)
```

Prior to running this I have created two hdfs folders `wordcount/data` and `wordcount/out` and uploaded some text to the first using comman line.

A further issue is: I have two users on my computer: `hduser` and `master`. The first is created for the hadoop installation. I suppose that when I open R/RStudio I run it as `master`, and because hadoop is created for `hduser` there are some permission issues which lead to this error. As one can read on the 4. line of the output the system tries to find `master91618435`, which, as I suspect, should be `hduser...`.

My question is, how can I get rid of this error?

P.S.: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063117/hadoop-streaming-failed-with-error-code-5) is a similar question, but without any useful answer for me